# Forest or forests? Which is right?

Tags: grammatical-number

Is "forest" countable or not?

Having checked it in dictionary, it is still unclear to me. I'm considering to the following context.

> Our company owns 20 locations (or places) of forest across the country.

Comment: Or "Our company owns 20 forests across the country."

Comment: I'd say "Our company owns 20 forest locations (or places) across the country." Short answer - It's more a case of an adjectival use rather than count/noncount. Unless you are Weyerhaeuser, the places you own are forested, not forests.

Comment: Forested areas, forested properties. Or you could use a unit of measure, such as number of acres of forest.

Answer (score 3):

The noun form of *forest* is countable, eg "There are many forests in France".  However, it can be used as an adjective (meaning 'in a forest', or "from a forest"), and **adjectives** aren't pluralized.

For example, your sample sentence could be rewritten as

> "Our company owns 20 forest locations across the country."

which is using the adjectival form of "forest", and which states that you own locations (eg buildings) which are located **inside** forests.  If you own the forests themselves (which is less likely) you would just say *"Our company owns 20 forests across the country."*

Answer (score 1):

Forest is countable. You can use "There are many forests in the city".

There is an exception, When You mean on every forest in the world, It isn't countable.

http://www.greenfacts.org/en/forests/l-2/2-extent-deforestation.htm

This article use *How much forest is there on the planet and at what rate is it disappearing?* and not **How many**.